# Spring boot with authentication - login page not found (404)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have a problem with my spring application since I've tried to include some security things.

After building a small working app including angularJS I followed this [spring security tutorial](http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/30/part-5-integrating-spring-security-with-spring-boot-web/) but I can't get it started. When I try to access any part of the app, the security modul wants to redirect to http://localhost:8080/login... but can't find it.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
>   No message available

Maybe I'm just missing a small thing but I can't figure out what it is ^^

Here is my code...

**folder structure:**

```
src/main/java
 +-Application.java
 +-SecurityConfiguration.java

src/main/resources
 +-static
  +-index.html
 +-templates
  +-login.html
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>

<!-- Additional lines to be added here... -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1100-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

**Application.java:**

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ViewControllerRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfiguration.java:**

```
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.servlet.configuration.EnableWebMvcSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http
                .formLogin().failureUrl("/login?error")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("password").roles("USER");
    }
}
```

**login.html:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<title>Spring Security Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div th:if="${param.error}">Invalid username and password.</div>
    <div th:if="${param.logout}">You have been logged out.</div>
    <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">
        <div>
            <label> User Name : <input type="text" name="username" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label> Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Sign In" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I followed my own hint in the comment above and figured out I forgot `extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` at my `Application.class`

That solved the Problem!

Comment: This approach is now deprecated. See https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-tutorial for more recent examples using @EnableWebMvc and the WebMvcConfigurer interface.

Answer (score 1):

Where is your `login.html` located? Can you get to `/login` directly in a browser? I suspect you don't have your `ViewResolver` set up properly. If you can't go directly to `/login`, that's your problem. Look at application.properties values `spring.view.prefix` and `spring.view.suffix`.

If you **can** get there directly, you might be dealing with a hidden error. Spring Boot includes an AutoConfiguration that swallows exceptions and throws a 404. You might want to exclude it (change `@EnableAutoConfiguration` to `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class)`. That will enable you to see any errors that are thrown during the request processing.

Comment: My `login.html` ist located in `src/main/resources/templates` and I also copied it to `src/main/resources/static` (where all the other .html files are)

But I can't go directly to `/login` either. The tutorial - part **_Registering the Login Action_** says I just need to specify this mapping in my application configuration... like I did.

The only thing is, when I want to use `@Override` I get an Eclipse error 
`The method addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry) of type Application must override or implement a supertype method Application.java`. So I simply removed the `@Override`

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to define the following in a controller which resolved 404

```
@GetMapping("/login")
public String loginPage(Model model) {
    return "login";
}
```